# One of two custom Active Record validation methods is ignored even when condition is met (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My model has two custom ActiveRecord validation methods which are supposed to fire at the same time. However, no matter what I do, only method A (`setup_ssh_user`) is executed, never B (`save_ssh_on_server`).

I have already tried:

- using `byebug` and `Rails.logger.info('funciton B is called')` to check that method B really is never called
- commenting out method A
- renaming method B
- using `validate` instead of `before_validation`
- exchanging the code of method A and B

```rb
class Postgresql < ApplicationRecord
  # Validations
  validates :host, presence: true
  validates :port, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :dbname, presence: true
  before_validation :setup_ssh_user, :save_ssh_on_server, on: :create, if: :ssh_tunnel?
  before_validation :save_ssh_on_server, on: :update, if: :ssh_public_key_changed?
  validate :rollback_ssh_setup, if: :rollback_needed

  # Associations
  has_one :target, as: :resource, inverse_of: :resource, autosave: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :target, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  def rollback_needed
    return self.target.deleted || errors[:ssh_public_key].any? || errors[:ssh_user].any? ? true : false
  end

  def rollback_ssh_setup
    status1, status2, status3 = SshTunnel::Setup.new().rollback_ssh_setup(self.ssh_user, self.ssh_public_key)
    if status1.success? && status2.success? && status3.success?
      return true
    else
      errors.add(:ssh_tunnel, "Rollback of ssh setup failed.")
      return false
    end
  end

  def setup_ssh_user
    status = SshTunnel::Setup.new().create_user(self.ssh_user)
    if status.success?
      return true
    else
      errors.add(:ssh_user, "User Creation failed, please try again.")
      return false
    end
  end

  def save_ssh_on_server
    Rails.logger.info("ssh saving function called")
    status = SshTunnel::Setup.new().save_public_key(self.ssh_public_key, self.ssh_user)
    if status.success?
      return true
    else
      errors.add(:ssh_public_key, "Saving SSH Key failed, please try again.")
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Since both methods are super similar I don't understand why one never get's executed and the other is. Maybe I misunderstood how ActiveRecord validations work? Would be very thankful for any improvement or debugging suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you want to return true on a succesfull validation, this is already implied. You should only set an error in case there is something wrong. I have some doubts whether this is really something you want to take care of in the validation cycle... you could also consider moving this into a regular before_save or even earlier in the cycle.

Comment: Thanks @bo-oz for your answer! I would like to validate, that the two methods ran through successfully, therefore the `before_validation`. You were right, the `if status.success?` was unnecessary, sadly it is not the root of my problem. `save_ssh_on_server` is still not being called.

Comment: So it seems you also defined `on: :create`, and `on: :update`, so they will never run at the same time, as it is either one of those two methods.

Comment: That's true, but the `on: :create` before validation has both methods at once in it. I also tried splitting the `on: :create` before validation in two, one for each method, but still nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not really an answer to why the above code is not working but I found a workaround - I hope this helps others who might experience something similar.

I substituted:

`before_validation :setup_ssh_user, :save_ssh_on_server, on: :create, if: :ssh_tunnel?`

with:

```
  before_validation on: :create do
    if self.ssh_tunnel
      self.setup_ssh_user
      self.save_ssh_on_server
    end
  end
```